# Backup of svn repository to shared folder on NAS fails

Tags: svn, backup, visualsvn-server

I want to set up an automatic incremental backup of my SVN repositories.
Doing that to a local folder of the same PC seems to work, but if I try to write the files directly to a shared folder (I tried 2 different QNAP nas boxes) I get various errors, always a couple of hundred lines.

I tried

```
svnadmin hotcopy C:\SVNRepos\RalfStein \\Nas\home\svn\RalfStein
```

After 202 lines it returned

> svnadmin: E720059: Can't move
> '\oldnas\home\svn\RalfStein\db\revprops\svn-1AA28066' to
> '\oldnas\home\svn\RalfStein\db\revprops\203': Unerwarteter
> Netzwerkfehler.

("Unerwarteter Netzwerkfehler" means "unexpected network error".)

On a different nas it returned after 799 lines:

> svnadmin: E720059: Can't close file
> '\nas\home\svn\RalfStein\db\revprops\svn-44790380': Unerwarteter
> Netzwerkfehler.

I've shut down the svn service, so there's no danger of someone working on svn in the meantime. Still same problem.

In don't want to use "dump" as it's not incremental.
I can manually copy the entire repository and that seems to work. However, I'd like to understand where the problem is coming from.

System:

- VisualSVN V4.3.6 on Windows10
- svnadmin --version : 1.14.1
- The NAS (a QNAP TS453d) provides the SMB-share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What protocol does your NAS use?
- Do you see errors when you run the [`Backup-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Backup-SvnRepository) PowerShell cmdlet?
- What VisualSVN Server version and the version of SVN command-line tools are you using? I.e., what `svnadmin --version` says?

Note that you can consider the built-in [Backup and Restore](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/backup/) feature. It supports backup scheduling, encryption, incremental backups and backups to remote shares and Azure Files cloud. See [KB106: Getting Started with Backup and Restore](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00106/) and [KB137: Choosing backup destination](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00137/).

> I want to set up an automatic incremental backup of my SVN
> repositories. Doing that to a local folder of the same PC seems to
> work, but if I try to write the files directly to a shared folder (I
> tried 2 different QNAP nas boxes) I get various errors, always a
> couple of hundred lines.

From what I see, an unexpected network error indeed occurs when you hotcopy the repository onto your NAS. Please, double-check that you are using up-to-date Subversion command-line tools (what `svnadmin --version` says?).

> I've shut down the svn service, so there's no danger of someone
> working on svn in the meantime. Still same problem.

You don't need to stop the server's services when you run [`svnadmin  hotcopy`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/hotcopy/):

[[[

This subcommand makes a “hot” backup of your repository, including all hooks, configuration files, and, of course, database files. **You can run this command at any time and make a safe copy of the repository, regardless of whether other processes are using the repository.**

]]]

Comment: I edited the description to provide the info you ask for. I din't manage to run the cmdlet, here https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00165/ is says, I can start Powershell vom Action/All tasks/Start powershell. I don't see that on my installation. (I installed on a 2nd PC, same there). I will now try to update VisualSVN from Community to Essential Edition...

Comment: With the Essential Edition scheduled backups work, thanks. It remains the question why hotcopy fails on a NAS drive (so I leave that marked as unanswered for now), but for me upgrading to Essential and using the built-in backup instead of svnadmin is a perfect solution now. Thanks.

Comment: @ralfiii I'm not sure now why `svnadmin hotcopy` fails to generate the backup in your case. I think that you could ask in the [users@ Apache Subversion mailing list](https://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html#users-ml).